# Changing the Event form in Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm new to Google Apps Script and trying to learn its ins and outs as well as it's limitations. Right now I'm trying to implement a change in the Event form on Google Calendar. I'm trying to add custom HTML to the form. Based on the documentation, this is possible for other apps (e.g. Spreadsheet) but I'm not able to see how I can do it in Calendar. I'm looking for the getUI() function on either the Calendar or Event but the reference(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event) doesn't have it. Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: Do you mean something like a sidebar or dialog box?  Unfortunately, your question does not adhere to stack overflow guidelines. It's too broad.   your question does not include any code.[Apps Script group](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: Hi Sandy, yes something like the dialog box. In fact, I was looking more into adding custom HTML inside the Event form. I see how I can do it in Spreadsheet (code below) but not sure how to do it on Claendar's Event - doesn't seem to have the getUI() method.
Example code for Spreadsheet 
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');

Comment: The code looks a bit like part of your research. Add it to your question. By the way, Google Calendar isn't a container of Google Apps Script projects.

Comment: There is no way to bind some HTML input to the Calendar with Apps Script.  If you want to create something that enhances the Calendar, maybe there is a way to do that with a Chrome Store browser extension?  I don't know.

Comment: @SandyGood: See [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks.  Good to know.

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP already mentioned, the Calendar Service for Google Apps Script doesn't include the getUI() method. It's worth to say that it doesn't have another similar method, so it's not possible to extend / modify the built-in Google Calendar event form. With Google Apps Script, the alternative is to create a custom event form with the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

From the above link

> HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML
>
> The [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html) lets you serve web pages that can interact with
>   server-side Apps Script functions. It is particularly useful for
>   building web apps or adding custom user interfaces in Google Docs,
>   Sheets, and Forms. You can even use it to generate the body of an
>   email.

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks for this. It's what I was following. The challenge is that once I create the HTML I need to add it to the UI. This works in Spreadsheet via the getUI() method but not sure how to do it in Calendar since the method doesn't exist. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Stefan: I reworded my answer.

Comment: Great, makes sense. Thanks Ruben.